# Missing Option.default in OCaml 4.01.0

Tags: ocaml, ml

I'd to use the `String.Set.choose some_set` to pick a string from a set.

This method returns StringOption, but I want to use another method with the return value of the second, hence I'd like to cast the StringOption into string.

I know according to OCaml docs ([link here](http://ocaml-lib.sourceforge.net/doc/Option.html)) that    `Option.default` is supposed to do that but from some reason it's missing (although the    `Option` with all the rest of the methods exists).

Is there a way to workaround this or let my next method to accept StringOption?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, those are not the OCaml docs :-) It's an add-on library. That particular repository is obsolete (like almost everything else on Sourceforge), and its Option module has been incorporated into [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org) as the [BatOption](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatOption.html) module. Batteries is also an add-on library, but is one of the most widely used ones.

You can write your own function to extract a string from a string option, as long as you decide what you want to do when the value is actually `None`. In that case, there's no string of course.

One possibility is just to raise an exception in that case. If you're positive there's always a string, the exception will never happen. If it does happen, you know you have a problem. So, you could write a function like this:

```
let string_of_string_option so =
    match so with
    | None -> failwith "string_of_string_option, no string"
    | Some str -> str
```

(This function works like `List.hd`; i.e., it's a partial function that raises an exception when the input is not valid.)

You can also write your own version of `default`; it's an extremely simple function:

```
let my_default dflt vo =
    match vo with
    | None -> dflt
    | Some v -> v
```

A good way to get current OCaml docs is to go through [ocaml.org](http://ocaml.org/docs/).

Another very popular add-on library is Jane Street Core, described [here](http://janestreet.github.io). It has a function named `Option.value` that is similar to the `default` function you were looking for. (In fact, the name seems a little better to me.)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey! Thanks for the quick answer! I trued something similar but during compilation I get     `Error: Unbound value string_of_string_option`. I'm calling it     `with string_of_string_option String.Set.choose free_Vars`

Comment: Hmm. I'm not saying there is already a function named `string_of_string_option`. I'm saying you can write your own pretty easily. You can also write your own version of `default`. Or you can use the `default` from OCaml Batteries Included. You have many options :-)